# How to extend body-parser IncomingRequest type?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I want to add to my `express` web server a `rawBody` parameter.
Typescript fails to compile and says it doesn't recognize `rawBody` for `IncomingMessage`.

`Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'.ts(2339)`

```js
    this.app.use(
      express.json({
        verify: (req, res, buf) => {
          req.rawBody = buf;
        },
      })
    );
```

I tried adding `types.d.ts` file to my project, but it still didn't work.

```js
declare module http {
  export class IncomingMessage {
    rawBody?: Buffer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems you have defined the rawBody in incomingMessage correctly?
are you using ternary operator? if yes it is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I have defined `rawBody` in `IncomingMessage`. But I don't understand how ternary operator relate to this question...